# Split string but returns separate words

Tags: python, pandas, string, split

I was working on a project to identify partial matches of a string and a list.

The idea is to let python loop through a condition list and check whether the specified string contains any matches to the list.

FYI, the string I have is several filenames.

I tried to code as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import re

from re import split

df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\py\con.xlsx")
id = df.iloc[:,3].tolist()
file_dir = "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Python\Input"

#read filenames and split filename
for x in os.listdir(file_dir):
    f_name = os.path.basename(x[:-4])
    print(f_name)
    for fname in f_name:
        new_fn = fname.split(r'_|-', 6) #here I wanted to set max 6 split
        print(new_fn)

#set conditions loop, rename file
if any(ele in new_fn for ele in id):
  print("Success")
  #here I also wish to rename the file
else:
  print("Fail")
```

FYI, the string (file name) is like CS123-5_3 (1)

After run the code, the output is like below

```
CS123-5_3 (1)
['C']
['S']
['1']
['2']
['3']
['-']
['5']
['_']
['3']
['(']
['1']
[')']
Fail #here fail refers to the if any statement
```

But my expected output should be like below

```
['CS123', '-', '5', '_', '3', '(1)']
```

Anyone can advice how I should improvise this code?

Comment: Be careful with backslash inside double-quoted strings. Your first one uses `r"` which properly escapes, the `file_dir` definition does not.

Comment: I may be miss-reading this but is your second for loop necessary? Won't it be looping over a string  ` for fname in f_name:`  so the `fname` will just be a single character in the loop when you are trying to split it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try using regex? https://regex101.com/r/wEymzI/1

*Example*

```
import re

string = "CS123-5_3 (1)"
print(re.split(r'(\w*\d*)(-)(\d*)(_)(\d*)\s(\(\d*\))', string))
# or 
print(re.findall(r'(\w*\d*)(-)(\d*)(_)(\d*)\s(\(\d*\))', string))

split_string = re.split(r'(\w*\d*)(-)(\d*)(_)(\d*)\s(\(\d*\))', string)

print(len(split_string))  # total items in split_string

# index and printing separately
for i, item in enumerate(split_string):
    print(i, item)
```

---

> [image]

Comment: hii @0m3r , thank you so much for the solution. I had tried on this method and its working now :)

Comment: just another question, as I applied this split in a for loop to iterate over a list of strings, the output is showing the string itself then only show the splitter list. And I am not able to store all the outputs after the string... is it because I'm not looping it correctly?

Comment: also see https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-for-loop-list/#:~:text=Using%20Python%20for%20loop%20to%20iterate%20over%20a,list%20to%20the%20item%20variable%20in%20each%20iteration.